# Delphi Windows Service - Wait for long task to complete before starting the service

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have Delphi Windows Service application, this service creates a data module and initialize some In-Memory tables.

Code to create data module has been written inside `ServiceExecute` event handler

```
procedure TMyService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
    if dm_Global = nil then
        dm_Global := Tdm_Global.Create( Application );

    while NOT Terminated do
    begin
        ServiceThread.ProcessRequests( True ); // if false add sleep(1000)
    end;
end;
```

Creation of `dm_Global` takes some time (around 1 minute) as it fills some In-Memory tables.

I have installed the service and running it. I was expecting that since creation of `dm_Global` takes some time , service's status will be `starting` in Windows Service Manager but is shows as `running` within few seconds of hitting the `Start` button.

Am I missing something or it is expected behavior of Windows Service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Service `OnExecute` event is called after the service has been started. So your `OnExecute` event handler (`ServiceExecute()`) is, by definition, running when the service is already in the "Running" state.

You should use the `OnStart` event to initialize your service.  The service will be in the "Starting" state until the `OnStart` event handler exits.

Comment: In which case, you can remove your `OnExecute` handler completely, since the default behavior of `TService` will call `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True)` for you.